# calling exist/not exist package dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a `PL/SQL` package as following (A piece of code):

```
if(IsRegisterMode)
    num_result := kwp_gep.register(var_name,var_family, bool_is_incomming);
```

My problem is : in some environment `kwp_gep` package exist and `IsRegisterMode` flag is true so `kwp_gep.register` called but in another environment `kwp_gep` package don't exist(not necessary) and `IsRegisterMode` flag is false.
With above explanation in second environment main package doesn't compile and show error : `kwp_gep does not exist`.
My question is: What is solution for this problem? I think exist a solution for dynamically execute `kwp_gep` procedures.

EDIT:
`kwp_gep.register` has a number as return value and `bool_is_incomming` and boolean.

Comment: Compile a stub (a package with empty implementation) for non-existing package in the second environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1: Conditional Compilation**

You could use conditional compilation, e.g.

```
$IF $$isregistermode $THEN
  kwp_gep.register(var_name,var_family);
$ENDIF
```

When you compile the package, you'd do something like this in the environments where the package exists:

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_CCFLAGS = 'isregistermode:true'
```

**Option 2: Dynamic execution**

```
if IsRegisterMode then
  execute immediate 'kwp_gep.register(:var_name,:var_family)'
  using var_name, var_family;
end if;
```

**Option 3: Stub**

(as per Egor's suggestion) in the environments that don't have `kwp_gep.register`, create a stub that never gets called, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE kwp_gep IS
PROCEDURE register (var_name in varchar2, var_family in varchar2);
END kwp_gep;
```

Note that it has no package body, so it will never execute without error. In your case it doesn't matter since your flag ensures it won't get called. If it does, then you know there's a problem in that environment.

Comment: Thanks. My package changes, I edit my question, please review it.my package has return value and a input parameter as boolean but your second solution don't work with this situation.

Comment: @MJM All the options are still valid. IMO it's a different issue if you have problems to apply the answer to a function-call instead of a procedure-call.

Comment: Best way is to do it with DYNAMIC sql.